# How to best share c# dlls in web app?

Tags: c#, git, dll, jenkins

I'm building a web app project and want to reference a few dlls from a desktop c# project. Both projects are pretty big.

This has all grown organically, so what we've done so far is include the dll projects in the web app solution which makes it easy for debugging. So at the moment all our code (desktop apps and web apps) sit in one big git repo and we build the web app and copy the code to a web server via Jenkins.

The time has come to manage the code better and split the repo into two. The problem I'm having is that I can't build the code anymore as is via Jenkins as the desktop app code (and dlls) will be gone from the Jenkins working directory (unless I create a common working directory).

I just want to get some ideas how to best manage the code:
 - How do I best include the desktop c# dlls in my web app solution?
 - Is there any way to still being able to debug the dlls if I don't include the dll projects in the web app (when debugging the web app)?
 - How do I keep the dlls in the web app solution up to date (say if I put them into the bin folder)?
 - Is there a way to not include the dlls in the repo, but have Jenkins rebuild and copy the dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your shared DLLs in a [nuget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) package in its binary format and have it referenced by both the desktop and the web application.

I don't know about the Jenkins part, but a quick google said that there is a [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nuget+Plugin) that support nuget.

[Creating nuget packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) is an easy and straight forward process with adding some meta data about the nuget in a nuspec file and calling nuget.exe with some parameters to create the package (nupkg) for you, that you can later reference in your project.

[Hosting nuget packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) to be found and used later, you will need to create a feed. it can be as simple as storing files in a folder somewhere and configuring your build tools (visual studio, MSBUILD, etc.) where to look to find nuget feeds.

referencing a nuget is done in visual studio via [nuget package manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c) plugin.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Can nuget packages be private though?

Comment: Yes, if they are hosted in your private nuget feed (which can be just a folder in your code repository or shared network path)